# how to show row index in datagrid in react js?

Tags: reactjs, datagrid

**I want to add a list of numbers to the top left side**, but there is no index in my API response, so I don't know how to do so. I noticed that there are numbers in datagrid pagination; is there any way to use it here?

[image: here i'm trying to display list of index in my id row]

Comment: I would suggest you to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors . That will help you asking questions to which you will have a higher chance to get an answer.

Comment: "the top left side" is too void, please describe it more clearly. Point it with an arrow.